# First Push with IOs-PushPlugin Cordova 2.5

Tags: ios, push-notification, cordova

I tried to ddo this tutorial from Holly Schinsky
http://devgirl.org/2012/10/19/tutorial-apple-push-notifications-with-phonegap-part-1/

The Plugin is installed, and I'm trying to get my first push

in my index.html I call the function app.initialize() from my src index.js

so this is, inside my index.js:

```
var app = {

initialize: function() {
this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},

onDeviceReady: function() {
app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
tokenHandler:function(msg) {
console.log("Token Handler " + msg);
},
errorHandler:function(error) {
console.log("Error Handler  " + error);
alert(error);
},

successHandler: function(result) {
alert('Success! Result = '+result)
},

receivedEvent: function(id) {
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
// TODO: Enter your own GCM Sender ID in the register call for Android
if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
    pushNotification.register(this.successHandler, this.errorHandler,    {"senderID":"554205989074","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});
}
else {
    pushNotification.register(this.tokenHandler,this.errorHandler,{"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"app.onNotificationAPN"});
}
var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
},
// iOS
onNotificationAPN: function(event) {
var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
console.log("Received a notification! " + event.alert);
console.log("event sound " + event.sound);
console.log("event badge " + event.badge);
console.log("event " + event);
if (event.alert) {
    navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
}
if (event.badge) {
    console.log("Set badge on  " + pushNotification);
    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(this.successHandler, event.badge);
}
if (event.sound) {
    var snd = new Media(event.sound);
    snd.play();
}
},
// Android
onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
switch( e.event )
{
    case 'registered':
        if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
        {
            // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
            alert('registration id = '+e.regid);
        }
        break;

    case 'message':
        // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model
        // of the intermediary push server which must also be reflected in GCMIntentService.java
        alert('message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt);
        break;

    case 'error':
        alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
        break;

    default:
        alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
        break;
    }
}

};
```

Sorry if its too much code, but I don't know exactly where to start. I'm pretty new to this, but I'll try to describe what happened:

- i call the function app.initialize
- My output in XCode gives me this: [LOG] Received Event: deviceready
- so because my event is 'deviceready' then app.recievedEvent should start, right?
- and because my Device is an IOs-Device pushNotification.register should start, right?

--> but nothing happens (beside I#m getting the output in Xcode: [LOG] Received Event: deviceready)

I don't recieve a Push-Notification on my device

---

here the code from my php-file:

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert.pem');


$socketClient = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);


$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'test message', 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '2');
$payload['id'] = 666;

$payload = json_encode($payload);


$deviceToken = str_replace(' ', '', $data['deviceToken']);


$message = pack('CnH*', 0, 32, $deviceToken);


$message = $message . pack('n', strlen($payload));

$message = $message . $payload;


fwrite($socketClient, $message);


fclose($socketClient);
```

Answer (score 1):

To receive push notification, you need to send a notification. Did you set already a server to do that. In the exemple of DevGirl, she use the node.js serveur to send push notification. 
If you follow her post, your phone should be set correctly to receive the notification.

If you need a push service, I have a Csharp code to do that

Comment: oh ok, thank you. I thought at this point in the tutorial everything is set right, that I should receive a notification like in the screenshot. Well it makes sense, that it ain't that way. I used to have an Xcode-app (no phonegap) where i did send a notification from an outside php-file from my server - see the code in the other answer. Is ist possible to send a notification from this file to the apple-notifications-center to my device? I haven't done a thing with node.js or Csharp yet...